# SQL Server Management Studio Express Data Import

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server Management Studio Express and trying to import my access tables to SQL database.  In the blogs I have read I can do it from Tasks>>>>Import Data BUt my Tasks menu does not contain any Import Data.   It only contains

Detach, Shrink, Backup, Restore, Generate Scripts.
What is the problem with my Server Management Studio Express

What shall I do to import data?
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: Hmm.. I have Import data option on my tasks menu. All i can think of right now is that perhaps you are logged in as a user without enough permissions. What are you logged in as?

Comment: I am logged in as Administrator

Comment: did you try using `Bulk insert` query?

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using?  (2005?)

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the Express version, so I may not be able to help you.  However, if you're not seeing the Import option from the tasks menu, [per this site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/546f4407-0aa4-4b04-96f3-e6f0ba39a9d1/), you can either

1. Export from MS Access
2. Download the Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Toolkit: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65111
3. Run  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe"

*NOTE: As a side note, the forum referenced above was for SQL Express 2005 (hence the path containing version 90)*

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new blank database and then right click on the database you should have "Tasks" > Import Data.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/12ba865f-c982-4d85-8db4-e3b787a7a478/sql-server-management-studio-express-data-import), SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 does not offer the Import/Export option at all, but Microsoft added that feature in the 2008 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql management studio for this purpose install over on your current express version and you can import export then.